# objective-c protocol adopted in swift

Tags: ios, delegates, appdelegate

This is objective c protocol placed in framework I use

```
@protocol AWSDKDelegate <NSObject>

/*
 * @abstract    AWSDKDelegate initialization lifecycle notifications to inform your app of success or failure
 in SDK initialization and profile retrieval.
 */
- (void)initialCheckDoneWithError:(NSError*) error;
- (void)receivedProfiles:(NSArray*)profiles;

/*
 * @abstract    AWSDKDelegate Action Notifications used to inform your app to take various action
 * @discussion  stopNetworkActivity and resumeNetworkActivity are not supported on iOS 9
 */
- (void)wipe;
- (void)lock;
- (void)unlock;
- (void)stopNetworkActivity;
- (void)resumeNetworkActivity;
@end
```

After creating bridge header I'm trying to adopt it in my app written in Swift

```
//MARK: AWSDKDelegate Methods

    func initialCheckDoneWithError(error: NSError!) {}
    func receivedProfiles(profiles: NSArray!) {}
    func unlock() {}
    func wipe() {}
    func stopNetworkActivity() {}
    func resumeNetworkActivity() {}
```

But still got this error:

```
Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'AWSDKDelegate'
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Forget to implement lock method
2) I don't know why, but it turns out the appropriate way of using `NSArray` is `[AnyObject]`. So func `receivedProfiles(profiles: [AnyObject]!)` instead of `func receivedProfiles(profiles: NSArray!)`

Anyway, I'm wonder why XCode hasn't a more detailed description of those type of errors..